# Dynamicaly making a link status to down in ns2

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have a simple network topology with about 16 nodes and links between them which I made them using this :

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 16} {incr i} {
    set n($i) [$ns node]
}

for { set i 0 } {$i <16} {incr i} {
    $ns duplex-link $n($i) $n([expr ($i+1) %16]) 1Mb 10ms DropTail
    $ns duplex-link $n($i) $n([expr ($i+4) %16]) 1Mb 10ms DropTail
}
```

then there is a cbr traffic originator from node 0 to node 8 with a simple udp traffic. Now I have a procedure that every 0.5 samples the arrived traffic at node 8 with a LossMonitor and then based on a threshold will remove(down) specific links within the topology.like this :

```
set sink0 [new Agent/LossMonitor]
$ns attach-agent $n(8) $sink0
$ns connect $udp0 $sink0
```

and the procedure :

```
proc record {} {
    global sink0 a sum n
    set ns [Simulator instance]
    set time 0.5
    set bw0 [$sink0 set bytes_]
    set now [$ns now]
    set sum [expr $bw0+$sum]
    if {$sum >= $a } {  
        for { set i 0 } {$i <16} {incr i} {
            set myLink [[$ns link $n(0) $n(4)] link]
            $myLink down (this is the error)
        }
        return
    }
    $sink0 set bytes_ 0
    $ns at [expr $now+$time] "record"
}
$ns at 0.5 "record"
$ns at 5.0 "finish"
```

Now my problem is at the line $myLink down,which gives me this error:

```
ns: record: 
    (_o83 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o83 cmd down"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o83" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$myLink down"
    (procedure "record" line 11)
    invoked from within
"record"
```

Also other #myLink commands such as setting delay and etc works,but the problem is with the down command.
Can you tell me what is the problem?

Update: This is the whole tcl file: http://pastebin.com/4kt2TxBX

Comment: The actual error message is really unhelpful: “`ns: record:`”? :-(

Comment: That is the whole copy of the error that I'm getting after running the simulation

Comment: Actually $ `ns saeed_ek.tcl` is creating a result : out_dv.nam 549.7kB, out_dv.tr 214.3kB. Please run `nam out_dv.nam` . The errors : Any faulty simulation.tcl could spit out similar errors.

Comment: Well yes,but the strange thing is that now the simulation stops at 3(which is the time that the threshold is met) and I don't see any of the required links to go down. @KnudLarsen

Comment: Well, it needs someone who actually understands the error messages produced by ns2 in that case. I do not know if your code is idiomatic or not; it doesn't appear obviously wrong to me (assuming that the `link` methods do sensible things when used as described) but I'm a _general_ Tcl programmer and not a user of ns2 or oTcl (the OO extension that ns2 uses — it's now the _only_ remaining common user of oTcl).

Comment: @DonalFellows thank you,So what would you do if you'd wanted to dynamically down a link in your simulation?

Comment: When I wrote simulations, the links corresponded to bits of aluminium on a CPU. It simply _wasn't_ dynamic in that way…